# What's the difference between due < now() and due < "0"

Tags: jira, jql

I have two JQL queries:

1. due >=  "0"
2. due >=  now()

Is there a difference?  I cannot find a reference description for what "0" means.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no difference. The second query

> ```
> 2. due >= now()
> ```

compares `due` to the current date. The first query

> ```
> 1. due >= "0"
> ```

compares `due` to the current date MINUS "0" offset days or weeks, which is again equal to the current date.

Compare the Atlassian [Advanced searching - fields reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-fields-reference-764478339.html#Advancedsearching-fieldsreference-DueDueDatedueDateDue) page:

> Or use "w" (weeks) or "d" (days) to specify a date relative to the current date. Be sure to use quote-marks (").